Flutter Widget state not consistent while updating checkbox list array
I have a stateful widget that utilizes flutter_multi_select_items package. The issue I'm having is the alternating state only changes once upon first click. I want the checkboxes to be unclicked by default, yet the selected input requires a value and it remains true after each state change event. How do I properly alternate adding/removing id values from the checkbox array and keeping the state in sync with the values being added and removed?
Logs
flutter: true
flutter: 1
flutter: removing add on
flutter: []

Performing hot reload...                                                
Reloaded 1 of 1718 libraries in 426ms (compile: 21 ms, reload: 156 ms, reassemble: 174 ms).
flutter: false
flutter: adding add-on
flutter: [1]
flutter: true
flutter: removing add on
flutter: []
flutter: true

class _AddServiceState extends State<AddService> {
  final MultiSelectController<dynamic> _multiSelectcontroller = MultiSelectController();
   List<dynamic> checkAddons = [];
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   List<dynamic> _addOns = widget.service_profile['service_add_ons'];
   return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(title: 'Adjust your add-ons')
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _multiSelectcontroller.selectAll();
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('Select All')),
                              Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    MultiSelectCheckList(
                                      maxSelectableCount: 5,
                                      textStyles: const MultiSelectTextStyles(
                                          selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      itemsDecoration: MultiSelectDecorations(
                                          selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.indigo
                                                  .withOpacity(0.8))),
                                      listViewSettings: ListViewSettings(
                                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                              const Divider(
                                                height: 0,
                                              )),
                                      controller: _multiSelectcontroller,
                                      items: List.generate(
                                          _addOns.length,
                                          (index) => CheckListCard(
                                              value: _addOns[index]['id'],
                                              title:
                                                  Text(_addOns[index]['title']),
                                              subtitle:
                                                  Text(_addOns[index]['price']),
                                              selectedColor: Colors.white,
                                              checkColor: Colors.indigo,
                                              selected:
                                                  checkedAddons.indexOf(_addOns[index]['id'], index) == index,
                                              enabled: true,
                                              checkBoxBorderSide:
                                                  const BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.blue),
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          5)))),
                                      onChange:
                                          (allSelectedItems, selectedItem) {
                                        if (allSelectedItems.isNotEmpty) {
                                          checkedAddons = [];
                                          checkedAddons
                                              .addAll(allSelectedItems);
                                          return;
                                        }

                                        print(checkedAddons
                                            .contains(selectedItem));
                                        if (checkedAddons
                                            .contains(selectedItem)) {
                                          print('removing add on');

                                          setState(() {
                                            checkedAddons.removeWhere((item) => item == selectedItem);
                                          });

                                          print(checkedAddons);
                                        } else {
                                          print('adding add-on');
                                          setState(() {
                                            checkedAddons.add(selectedItem);
                                          });
                                          print(checkedAddons);
                                        }
                                      },
                                      onMaximumSelected:
                                          (allSelectedItems, selectedItem) {
                                        //    CustomSnackBar.showInSnackBar(
                                        //       'The limit has been reached', context);
                                      },
                                    )
       
]
         )
     )
  }
});


put checkAddons outside the build method

If you put checkAddons inside the build method when you use setState(), the method build is recalled, then the checkAddons will be reset to the default value of [], which will make this error. The solution is to put checkAddons outside the build method.
There is an example for flutter_multi_select_items:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_multi_select_items/flutter_multi_select_items.dart';

class MultiSelectExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MultiSelectExample> createState() => _MultiSelectExampleState();
}

class _MultiSelectExampleState extends State<MultiSelectExample> {
  final MultiSelectController _controller = MultiSelectController();
  final List<Map<String, String>> items = [
    {'id': '1', 'title': 'Apple'},
    {'id': '2', 'title': 'Banana'},
    {'id': '3', 'title': 'Cherry'},
    {'id': '4', 'title': 'Date'},
    {'id': '5', 'title': 'Elderberry'},
  ];

  List<dynamic> selectedItems = []; // Manage items selected

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Multi Select Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text('Selected items: $selectedItems')),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('Show Selected Items'),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _controller.selectAll();
                  setState(() {
                    selectedItems = items.map((e) => e['id']).toList();
                  });
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text('All items selected')),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Select All'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: MultiSelectCheckList(
              controller: _controller,
              items: List.generate(
                items.length,
                (index) => CheckListCard(
                  value: items[index]['id'],
                  title: Text(items[index]['title']!),
                  checkColor: Colors.white,
                  selectedColor: Colors.indigo,
                ),
              ),
              textStyles: const MultiSelectTextStyles(
                selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              itemsDecoration: MultiSelectDecorations(
                selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.8),
                ),
              ),
              onChange: (allSelectedItems, selectedItem) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedItems = allSelectedItems;
                });
                print('Selected items: $selectedItems');
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I moved the checkedAddons array outside of the build method but now I receive true all of the time

You must init the chedAddons type List, and set the default value to false for all items.

Would you like to add a working example for the package? https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_select_items

@DWCod3r  I've just added a working example for the package, let's check it out.
